# How to include jar in ant build from pom.xml maven dependency

Tags: maven, ant, compilation, dependencies

I want to include jars that is imported using pom.xml in ant build. My project configuration is complicated. This is build.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="help" >
    <!--
        ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
        ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
        ~ See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional
        ~ information regarding copyright ownership.
        ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
        ~
        ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
        ~
        ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        ~ limitations under the License.
        -->

    <!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
         It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
         Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />


    <!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
         'android' tool to add properties to it.
         This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.diran
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
         files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
         get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
         This must be done before we load project.properties since
         the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>

    <!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.

         This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
         dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
         (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <!--
        Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
        This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
            -pre-build
            -pre-compile
            -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                           Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                           If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
            -post-package
            -post-build
            -pre-clean
    -->
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

    <!-- Import the actual build file.

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <import> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole content of build.xml
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, replacing the <import> task.
             - customize to your needs.

         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: VERSION_TAG -->
    <property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
    <property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/uibuild.xml" />


</project>
```

I can build using both ant and maven . However, i need jar file in bin folder. Therefore, i have to use ant build. But it does not see maven dependencies. How can i add jars to ant build ?

Thanks

EDIT: compiles in Eclipse. Eclipse sees maven dependencies however IntelliJ fails. I guess it is a config problem.

Comment: Migrate the build to Maven and don't use Ant anymore and never try to make a combination of this cause this is the way to hell..

Comment: you are right. in maven build, the output jar file is different. i could not understand why.